# Open activity after push notification clicked

Tags: android

Hey can you help me with your final code for the broadcastreceiver which opens links to the browser when clicked? i'm having a little trouble.

Comment: Please add some context to your question, it sounds like you are replying to someone, at the very least you could link their question in yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://your weblink here"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
```